# where to insert my todo in reactJs using axios post request?

Tags: reactjs, axios

where to write axios post request to insert todo into database.If I write axios post request in componentDidUpdate() whenever click on checkbox for todo_completed status it will insert in database. duplicate record maintains fro true and false. i dont understand where to call post request in todoApp.jsx
Here is my Code
todoapp.jsx

```
    var React = require('react');
    var TodoSearch = require('TodoSearch');
    var AddTodo = require('AddTodo');
    var TodoList = require('TodoList');
    var axios= require('axios');
    var TodoApp=React.createClass({
        getInitialState:function(){
            return{
                todo_completed:false,
                strSearchText:'',
                todos:[]

            };
        },
        componentDidMount:function(){
            var that=this;
            axios.post('/displaytodo').then(function (response){
                console.log("display");
                var todos=response.data;
                console.log(todos);
                that.setState({
                    todos:response.data
                });
            }).catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            });

        },
        componentDidUpdate:function(){
            var todo_text="";
            var todo_completed="";
            this.state.todos.forEach(function(todo){
                todo_text= todo.todo_text;
                todo_completed=todo.todo_completed;
            });
//insert todo in database
            axios.post('/addtodo',{
                todo_text:todo_text,
                todo_completed:todo_completed

            }).then(function (response) {

                console.log("data");
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
            },
        handleAddTodo:function(todo_text){
            alert("new todo "+todo_text);
                    //insert query needed to add todo
             this.setState({
                todos:[
                ...this.state.todos,
                {
                    todo_text:todo_text,
                    todo_completed:false    
                }
                ]
             });
                },
        handleToggle:function(todo_id){
            var updatedTodos=this.state.todos.map((todo)=>{
                if(todo.todo_id===todo_id){
                    todo.todo_completed=!todo.todo_completed;
                }
                return todo;
            });
            //update query required for completed status
            this.setState({
                todos:updatedTodos
            })
            //alert(id);
        },
        handleSearch:function(boolShowCompleted,strSearchText){
            this.setState({
                boolShowCompleted:boolShowCompleted,
                strSearchText:strSearchText.toLowerCase()

            });
        },
        render:function(){
            var urlValue = this.props.params.sessionValue;
            console.log(urlValue);
            var {todos}=this.state;
            return(
                <div>
                    {urlValue}
                    <TodoSearch onSearch={this.handleSearch}/>
                    <TodoList todos={todos} onToggle={this.handleToggle}/>
                    <AddTodo onAddTodo={this.handleAddTodo}/>
                </div>
                )
        }
    });
    module.exports=TodoApp;
```

**AddTodo.jsx**

```
 var AddTodo = React.createClass({
             handleSubmit: function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 var strTodoText = this.refs.strTodoText.value;
                 if (strTodoText.length > 0) {
                     this.refs.strTodoText.value = '';
                     this.props.onAddTodo(strTodoText);
                 } else {
                     this.refs.strTodoText.focus();
                 }
             },
             render: function() {

                     return ( < div >
                                 < form onSubmit = { this.handleSubmit } > 

                                 < input type = "text"  ref = "strTodoText" / > 
                                 < button className = "button" > Add Todo < /button> 
                                 </form > Add todo..... 
                              < /div>
                            )
             } 
 });
```

Comment: you should make your axios request inside the handleAddTodo method instead of componentDidUpdate.

Comment: when i add axios post rrequest in  handleAddTodo it contains last added todo in post request

Comment: I haven't seen your AddTodo component. but it should have an input field for todo_text and a button. on button click you should pass the newly typed todo_text to the handleAddTodo function.

Comment: yes exactly..here is my AddTodo.jsx  
var AddTodo=React.createClass({
handleSubmit:function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var strTodoText = this.refs.strTodoText.value;
   if (strTodoText.length > 0){
          this.refs.strTodoText.value = '';
          this.props.onAddTodo(strTodoText);
         } else {
         this.refs.strTodoText.focus();}
    },
 render:function(){
  return(
   <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     <input type="text" ref="strTodoText"/>
     <button className="button">Add Todo </button>
    </form>
   Add todo.....
   </div>)}
});
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an axios post request at two places,

1. In the `handleAddTodo` function, that gets called when the new todo is added. With this post request you need to insert a new entry into the table
2. In the `handleToggle` function, that gets called when you toggle the state of todo, With this post request you need to update the entry that already exist in your table

Comment: when i add axios post rrequest in handleAddTodo it contains last added todo in post request

Comment: yes you should be adding only the last added todo in the database isn't it

Comment: yes. meansif i added previously asd and next if i want add ggg then in post request contain asd not ggg

Comment: do you mean to say that when you are clicking addtodo button, in the handleTodo function you are getting the newTodo as the previously added todo

Comment: yes exactly.i want to say. i posted a screen shot of it

Comment: Can you console.log(strTodoText) in the handleSubmit function and see what you get

Comment: console.log(strTodoText) returns input text box value.when i enter to add todo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143754/discussion-between-vaishnavi-aher-and-shubham-khatri).